# jQuery live filter/search

Tags: html, jquery, search, input

I'm building an icon library where the user on the front end (submitting a form) can select an icon. I managed to get everything working as far as the selection process. Now, the final product will have over 400 icons, and i wanted to add a search (ajax, i guess) or autocomplete input where the user can type a couple of letters and it filter's out those icons.

They search will be filtering out some  with a class that has the prefix "icon-", so the search term would be whatever is after that prefix. (i.e: icon-TWIITER, icon-FACEBOOK, etc).

I started on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/28/

an example would be something like this :

http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/

http://cheeaun.github.io/jquery.livefilter/

I'm trying to stay away from jQuery plugins and try and figure this out before i resort to that. I'm using wordpress as the backend of the website.

as soon as the user types, it's already sorting out the icons that pertain to the input value.

My HTML Markup:

```
 <div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
 <span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon" style="display:none"></span>

 <button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>

 <div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">

     <div id="iconSearch">
         <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
         <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
     </div>

     <span class="icon-icon1"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon2"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon8"></span>

 </div>
```

JS:

```
 var iconVal = $(".icon_field").val();
 $('#selectedIcon').addClass(iconVal);

 $("#selectIconButton").click(function () {
     $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
     selectIcon($(this));
 });

 function selectIcon(e) {
     var selection = e.attr('class');
     $(".icon_field").val(selection);
     $("#iconSelector").hide();
     $('#selectedIcon').removeClass();
     $('#selectedIcon').addClass(selection).show();
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made an update on your jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/30 Just enter the classname e.g. icon-icon1 and all icons without icon-icon1 gets hidden

Comment: autocomplete is not exactly what im looking for although its close. I like autocomplete and have used it, but this is something less out of the box and more custom. something like this for example: http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/ without using the jquery plugin.

Comment: Made an update on your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/30/ Just enter the classname e.g. icon-icon1 and all icons without icon-icon1 gets hidden